# Asynchronous ObjectContext.SaveChanges()?

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous, backgroundworker, savechanges, objectcontext

I want the `SaveChanges` of the `ObjectContext` (Win apps) to save changes asynchronously, will show a marquee (or controllable?) progress bar (this I can easily implement) for the user while he is able to continue working.

I basically want to override the `SaveChanges` of the `ObjectContext`.

Has anyone thought about this before?

Comment: You should tag this question as *.net*. This will give it more visibility, and you might get more answers.

Comment: unfortunately there is no place for more than 5 tags.
i think the other tags is already .net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning**: The answer below is old and may not apply to the most recent versions of the framework in question.

I believe you need to use [Asynchronous Delegates](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Asynch_Delegates). It basically works like that:

1. You create a delegate from the method you want to call asynchronously;
2. You call `BeginInvoke` on the delegate, starting a call;
3. You do whatever else you need to do (e.g. animate a marquee);
4. You can either wait for the async call to finish, or check whether is has completed and keep animating the marquee if it isn't;

Comment: I know this question (and answer) is quite old, but I stumbled upon it, and I think I would add something: Your solution isn't very interesting resource wise. We want to use the async pattern during DB calls to allow the current thread to be freed (and eventually reused) during the IO operation. If you use a delegate, it will start a thread from the thread pool which will be blocked while the blocking IO operation (SaveChange). It means that performance wise, asynchronous delegates are useless in this case: Don't use this implementation on a webserver.

Comment: You're right. For long operations, this might not be a good idea. If you have a way to pass a callback to the underneath system and avoid blocking any threads, you must do that.

Comment: I found this from looking for `Save Changes Async` in reference to Entity Framework 6's new method. This answer is from 2009, far before that and so should not be considered relevant to that search even though it would seem a few others (potentially) have downvoted as a result of that. I would suggest changing your edit to reflect that this is not in reference to `SaveChangesAsync` and that the answer was from 2009 (because while scrolling it is not immediately obvious that is the case).

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework itself currently does not support asynchronous operations. Mainly because it's built on top of ADO.NET where this isn't supported either. ADO.NET isn't even thread safe by default.

You can use the delegate approach above or wrap it into Task. But that will not use any async calls even if the provider supports it. Also during this "background" operation you should not do anything with the ObjectContext (querying, adding objects, ...) as may result in corrupted state.

Related to multithreading you can read [this](http://blog.cincura.net/230902-multithreading-with-entity-framework/) post. It's older, but ideas are still valid.

*Edit 2013-04-17:*

EF6 (the next version, currently in alpha stage in time of writing) will support asynchronous operations, namely your requested `SaveChangesAsync`. It also extended ADO.NET model, so if the provider itself supports asynchronous execution it will be really asynchronous (else back to former behavior as there's nothing better (wise) to do).

Comment: ADO.NET 4.5 does support async operations (but EF5 does not). You have to enable it explicitely in the query string (async=True).